# Lose Properties when convert Cassandra column to java object

Tags: spring-data-cassandra

I use spring-data-cassandra-1.2.1.RELEASE to operate Cassandra database. Things all go well .But recent days I got a problem, when I using the code to get data:

```
public UserInfoCassandra selectUserInfo(String passport) {
    Select select = QueryBuilder.select().from("userinfo");
    select.setConsistencyLevel(ConsistencyLevel.QUORUM);
    select.where(QueryBuilder.eq("passport", passport));
    UserInfoCassandra userinfo = operations.selectOne(select,
            UserInfoCassandra.class);
    return userinfo;
}
```

there were many properties in userinfo , but I just get two the passport and uid properties.
  I debug into the method,got that the data getting from db is right,all properties were ready.but when converting them to a java object ,some disappear.. the converting code:

```
protected <T> T selectOne(Select query, CassandraConverterRowCallback<T> readRowCallback) {

    ResultSet resultSet = query(query);

    Iterator<Row> iterator = resultSet.iterator();
    if (iterator.hasNext()) {
        Row row = iterator.next();
        T result = readRowCallback.doWith(row);
        if (iterator.hasNext()) {
            throw new DuplicateKeyException("found two or more results in query " + query);
        }
        return result;
    }

    return null;
}
```

the row data is right ,but the result is wrong, who can help ?

Answer (score 0):

Most probably your entity class and it's corresponding relational model are mismatched.

Comment: I thought the wrong model is creating by hibernate or mongo ... but the project is complicated ,and hard to debug where the wrong class is made..